# POST to Urban Airship Push Notification iOS ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: http, ios6, asihttprequest, urbanairship.com

I have set up Urban Airship push notification register and handling on iOS and have tested it with CURL  terminal commands. I cannot, however, reproduce the same thing using ASIFormDataRequest. Can anyone who has done this show me how to either JSON serialize the data and send it using ASIHTTPRequest or something?

By the way, Urban Airship does not recognize my push on their web interface (the number of pushes does not increase), but I am able to get a response code 200 back from UA using this to authenticate:

```
[request setUsername:URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_KEY];
[request setPassword:URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_SECRET];
```

but I cannot seem to get it to send the notification to a device.

EDIT: Here is what my code looks like

```
NSDictionary *paramDict = 
@{
 device_tokens: @[@"mytoken",@"mytoken2"],
 aps: @{alert: @"alertText"},
 extras: @"myExtraParam",
 moreExtras: @"moreExtras"
};

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:paramDict];

   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
URLWithString:@"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/"]];
   [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

   [request appendPostData:data];

   [request setUsername:URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_KEY];
   [request setPassword:URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_SECRET];

   [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];

   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(pushSucceeded:)];
   [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(pushFailed:)];
   [request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: I think this is not working because I did not email UA to Allow Push From Devices. I have done so and will answer my question if that solves it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still not able to get airship to recognize my POST requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working. I guess it was an issue with my json serialization. Using NSJSONSerialization worked.

Here is my code for anyone else trying to get this to work.

```
 NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:paramDict
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", error);
} else {
    //Do something with jsonData


    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/"]];


    [request appendPostData:jsonData];

    [request setUsername:URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_KEY];
    [request setPassword:URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_SECRET];

    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(pushSucceeded:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(pushFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Urban Airship has documentation on integrating its SDK into your code.  But here are some hints to get you going.

You should override the below functions in your app's AppDelegate file that do something similar.  The UAirship is the manager class from the Urban Airship SDK.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {    
                // push notification
                //Init Airship launch options
                NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
                [takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

                // Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airship servers.
                // Please populate AirshipConfig.plist with your info from http://go.urbanairship.com
                [UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];
                ...
                }

        - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
            // Updates the device token and registers the token with UA
            NSLog(@"Registering for Devicetoken");
            [[UAirship shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];

            }        

        - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
            NSLog(@"Received remote notification: %@", userInfo);

            // possibly throw alert box to show the payload data in the userInfo object.
            }            

        - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *) error {
            NSLog(@"Failed To Register For Remote Notifications With Error: %@", error);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however if you reread my question, "I have set up Urban Airship push notification register and handling on iOS and have tested it with CURL terminal commands." (ie. I have the notification handling set up correctly, but I want to now SEND push notifications THROUGH iOS).

Comment: Those functions I gave are for iOS's AppDelegate file.